# Scroll and let content stick while animating

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm wondering how to achieve the following scroll animation, Where the STRATEGY and CREATIVE copy dock to the top and then animate while the user scroll, and when the animation is done, the page continue to scroll.

Please see page example here: https://www.mrsandmr.com/

[image: See image here]

What is this called in theory.

Thanks

Comment: see CSS position: sticky

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: @AlexGru This is perfect, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did some research on this as well, mainly inspired by the impressive web design on Apple product pages, like [this one](https://www.apple.com/airpods-3rd-generation/).

Here is a nice article I've found on Medium, which explains how to achieve such scrolling animations: [How to jazz up your website like Apple with JavaScript](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-jazz-up-your-website-like-apple-with-javascript-eed2bf227fec)

The result is available on the demo page [here](https://ww-apple.netlify.app/#/full).

As summarized in the TL;DR section:

```
To sum it all up, the mechanism of how it works is really just:
1. A scrolling container
2. position: sticky;elements
3. JavaScript that converts scroll position of the scrolling container to styles for sticky elements
4. (Sometimes) CSS transition property
```

### Animation logic for strategy/creative on "Mrs&Mr"

I would break it down to the following animation phases:

1. `translateX` from the outside (relative to scroll position) until the 2 elements reach the center of the viewport
2. Now `rotate` until 180° again relative to scroll position
3. Again, `translate` but out of the viewport